# Undefined reference to __dso_handle_ - compiling C++ on cygwin

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have a basic `Hello World` C++ program that I am trying to compile and run on `cygwin` with `g++`. The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  cout << "Hello world." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with: `g++ helloWorld.cpp -o h` results in the following error:
`/tmp/ccDO1S4J.o:helloWorld.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.__dso_handle[.refptr.__dso_handle]+0x0): undefined reference to`__dso_handle'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I have been reading up on some other threads that indicate that it might be a linker problem and that invoking the linker separately or with verbose output might lead to some more clues.

So, I did:
1. g++ -c helloWorld.cpp -o helloWorld.o  (this works - no errors).
2. ld -o h helloWorld.o causes a lot of undefined reference to __main or std::cout etc. errors.

I think this is a linking issue and that I need to link another library perhaps. Any pointers on how to solve this are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing `g++` via the installer application on `cygwin` worked.